# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-express

i am getting preceding error.I know that this question is duplicate of another questions answered here.but my problem differs from some points.when i try to connect from Sql Management Studio , there is no problem but when trying it from Visual Studio.it gives me the Error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the login process.

Comment: Are there any errors in the SQL server error log?

Comment: thanks for concerning .i have solved problem with re installing visual studio.